# Ethernet network on VMware not working

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine, internet-connection

I have a problem with connection network for internet.
The host is Windows 10 x64 and the guest in VMware is MacPro Yosemite for AMD

My config

Windows 10

Processor AMD

Network card Realtek GBE Family Controller

VMworkstation PRO and Player 12

OS X Niresh Yosemite for AMD

The mac operating properly. No problem during normal use. Unfortunately unable to connect to a network.

I try several solutions found on google.

I think of two possibilities.

The first is a bad network connection at my Windows with VMware Network Adapter. I do not know if it's VMnet 1 or VMnet 8 should be used. Then when I share or I make a bridge with these connections, VMware Network Adapter detects no internet connection. (See [image: VM_NA.png], [image: ShareEthernet.png] and [image: ShareVM.png])

The second would be that I do not have good drivers, I try to install with MultiBeast - Yosemit Edition, nothing happens, I just got this device in existing connection (see [image: SysPref.png])

I also tried installing the driver with KextBeast  http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/287161-new-driver-for-realtek-rtl8111/

I also discovered that the mac does not detect network card, is this correct? (see [image: NetworkCard.png])

I try on my two VM, the result is the same. I think I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for me the solution after multiple test on terminal with kext file etc...

From niresh, again

http://www.hackintosh.zone/file/118-all-in-one-network-solution-wireless-ethernet/